# what does 'php artisan migrate' do in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql

Previously, I was working with laravel and MySQL on port 3306. Then for some reasons, I tried to change the port to 3307 and deny access from localhost. The MySQL configuration is:

```
select User,Host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------+
| User             | Host        |
+------------------+-------------+
| root             | 192.168.1.2 |
| casual           | 192.168.1.6 |
| debian-sys-maint | 192.168.1.6 |
| mysql.sys        | 192.168.1.6 |
| root             | 192.168.1.6 |
+------------------+-------------+
```

Then I run **php artisan migrate** and expect the query to fail. However it still runs correctly, and create tables in MySQL. I try to use wireshark to listen on the port 192.168.1.6:3306/3307 but see nothing. So I wonder Why the command still succeeds since on default laravel only connects to MySQL via localhost:3306, and I have blocked this port. How can I force laravel to connect through 192.168.1.6:3307 so I can see packets in wireshark?

Comment: You can try this command in your terminal: sudo php artisan serve --port=3307